# pwm on logic gates from controller

Tags: digital-logic, design

friends..
In my project i need to control an LED based on AND operation so I like to AND  gate..

my question is does gates work under "PWM" pulse rate...

example:

Let us consider "1A,1B" as logic input and "1C" as output of logic gate...
now "1A" is kept under high,"1B" is controlled under "PWM" pulse...

Now can I get output from "1C" base don "PWM" pulse..?

Comment: So you like to AND gate? I, on the other hand, like to move it move it. More seriously, yes. Unless your PWM is so fast that the gate doesn't have the time to change state. Why would you think it may not work?

Comment: i dono about it whether it works or not...
this is my one idea to d so asked about it

Comment: Huh? What? I can't even make out what you're really asking.  Closing.  And -1 because we speak English here, not whatever dialect of Gibberish that is.

Answer (score 1):

This question is just asking about the basic operation of AND gates. I would strongly suggest you use the internet and do some research into the topic.

However, here is an answer:

An AND gets collects all inputs, and outputs a HIGH if, and only if, all inputs are HIGH. If any of the inputs are LOW, the output will be LOW.

Therefore, if you have a two input AND gate, one input is HIGH and one input is LOW, you get a LOW. If BOTH inputs are HIGH, you get a HIGH, if both inputs are LOW, you get a LOW.

So, back to your question: one input is HIGH, one input pulses between HIGH and LOW... You therefore get a LOW on the pulsed input is LOW, and HIGH when pulsed input is HIGH. So your output is the same as the pulsed input signal (while the other input is HIGH). The only difference between your output and your pulsed input will be the delay and ramp rate inherent in the AND gate device you are using.

Comment: if i used differnt pulse rate means it will work..?

Comment: Assuming that the AND get you are using can run at the frequency and voltage you are using, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

check this picture...
Can i get output same as PWM input..?
the input pwm pulse will vary frequently i can't say any fixed values...